# Powershell script to Find folders which have "Everyone" access and how to delete it

Tags: security, powershell, file-io

Need a Power Shell Script to find on a remote server which folders have "Everyone" access and How do I takeout this particular access (Remove Everyone group from Security)?

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines?

```
# 1. Get list of folders
$FolderList = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test\everyone -Directory -Recurse;

# 2. Iterate over folders and remove 'everyone' rules
foreach ($Folder in $FolderList) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName;
    $Everyone = $Acl.Access.Where({ $PSItem.IdentityReference -eq 'Everyone' });
    foreach ($Ace in $Everyone) {
        [void] $Acl.RemoveAccessRule($Ace);
    }
    Set-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName -AclObject $Acl;
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: This script requires PowerShell **version 4.0**, as it uses the Where "method syntax."

Comment: Iterating through a large set of folders / files twice over the network could be very, very slow. I would pipe gci into the get-acl cmdlet with the where command and then delete... It could cut the operation time in half or better - Still a +1 though

Answer (score 3):

Translating [Trevor's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21104630/1630171) to PowerShell v2/v3:

```psh
$rootFolder = '\\server\c$\some\folder'

# get locale-specific name for 'Everyone' security principal
$sid = New-Object Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier('S-1-1-0')
$everyone = $sid.Translate([Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value

Get-ChildItem $rootFolder -Recurse | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % {
  $acl = Get-Acl $_.FullName
  $acl.Access | ? { $_.IdentityReference -eq $everyone } | % {
    $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_)
  }
  Set-Acl $_.FullName -Acl $acl | Out-Null
}
```

In PowerShell v3 you can replace `| ? { $_.PSIsContainer }` with `-Directory`.

Note that this won't remove `Everyone` ACEs on the root folder itself, and it also won't remove inherited `Everyone` ACEs.